# Normal subgroup of triangle group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, finitely-generated, gap, hyperbolic-groups

Consider the hyperbolic (extended) triangle group $\Delta(2,3,7)=\langle a,b,c\mid a^2,b^2,c^2,(ab)^2,(bc)^3,(ca)^7\rangle$. I construct it in GAP as a finitely presented group, using the standard method:

```
FG:=FreeGroup("a","b","c");;
D:=FG/[FG.1^2,FG.2^2,FG.3^2,(FG.1*FG.2)^2,(FG.2*FG.3)^3,(FG.3*FG.1)^7];;
```

I next construct the set $W=\{\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_7\}\subset\Delta(2,3,7)$ as a particular set of seven (complicated) words in the generators $a,b,c$. I know from mathematical considerations that $W$ should generate an index-336 normal subgroup of $\Delta(2,3,7)$, i.e., $\Gamma=\langle W\rangle\triangleleft \Delta(2,3,7)$:

```
GAMMA:=Subgroup(D,gam);;
```

where `gam` is a list containing the seven words $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_7$ above.

Now here is my problem. GAP correctly recognizes that $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $\Delta(2,3,7)$ of index 336:

```
gap> IsSubgroup(D,GAMMA);
true
gap> Index(D,GAMMA);
336
```

but it doesn't seem to recognize that it is normal:

```
gap> IsNormal(D,GAMMA);
false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because the number '336' is so unique: Klein quartic-related? And more relevant to the question: what happens if you ask for the normalizer of $\Gamma$ in $D$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, $\Gamma$ should be isomorphic to the fundamental group of a genus-3 surface. 336 is the number of Schwarz triangles in Klein's "Hauptfigur" (hyperbolic 14-gon).
If I compute the index of $\Gamma$ in ```Normalizer(D,GAMMA)```, I get 14. I am even more confused now...

Comment: Can you get a presentation of `Normalizer(D,GAMMA)`? It sounds like you may have a small bug in your list of $\gamma_i$ somewhere and that's the most straightforward path I can think of to try and track it down.

Comment: I define (on purpose) the $\gamma_i$ as opposite-side pairings as opposed to pairings between sides $2k+1$ and $2k+6$ mod $7$, $k=0,\ldots,6$ in the actual Klein quartic. So maybe I shouldn't expect $\Gamma$ to be normal in $\Delta$?

Comment: Ok, I think my $\Gamma$ as defined is just not normal in $\Delta$. If I use the actual side-pairing transformations of the Klein quartic, I do find that the corresponding $\Gamma$ is normal. Both are index-336 in $\Delta$ but the normality structure is different. Thanks @StevenStadnicki for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the explicit list `gam` it is hard to give a certain reason, but a common error is to take elements of the free group (in your example `FG`) instead of the factor group (in your example `G`).

If you want to test, your quotient of order 336 is most likely $PGL(2,7)$:

```
gap> GQuotients(D,PGL(2,7));
[ [ a, b, c ] -> [ (2,5)(4,6)(7,8), (1,3)(2,7)(5,8), (3,6)(4,7)(5,8) ]]
```

Evaluate your words $\gamma_i$ in these permutations to see whether they are in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks! I made sure to use elements of ```D``` and not ```FG```. ```gam[i] in Kernel(GQuotients(D,PGL(2,7))[1]);``` for my originally defined ```gam``` returns false, but if I define new ```gamK[i]``` which are the standard side pairings of the Klein quartic, then ```gamK[i] in Kernel(GQuotients(D,PGL(2,7))[1]);``` returns true. So my original $\Gamma=\langle\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_7\rangle$ was not normal in $\Delta$, it turns out.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. So the world is sane again.